# How can i get query for .save() in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am updating a django model object. After setting value for each attribute when i call `obj.save()` it gaves me `OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`. I am desperate to know what is causing the following error. How can i get the the query?? As when save method fail because of above error it does not log query.
Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [django toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

it will give you list of all the queries that executed through Django (including .save()). To get your query you can do,

```
from django.db import connection, OperationalError
try:
    modelObj.save()
except OperationalError:
    print(connection.queries[-1])
```

Comment: Don't forget to set settings.DEBUG to True to view queries