# Django SQL Server ForeignKey that allows NULL

Tags: sql-server, django, postgresql, azure, foreign-keys

I've been struggling with this issue for some time. I'm switching one of my apps from Postgres to SQL Server database and I'm facing an issue with ForeignKey field. I'm running latest SQL Server version with Django 1.11 and using django-pyodbc-azure app.

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    dog = models.ForeignKey('Dog', related_name='+')

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', null=True, related_name='+')
```

When I try to insert a new record I get the following message:

```
dog = Dog.objects.create(name='Rex')
owner = Owner.objects.create(name='Mike', dog=dog)
dog.owner = owner
dog.save()
```

> ('23000', u"[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UQ__owner__EF6DECB9214EF1D9'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.owner'. The duplicate key value is (NULL). (2627)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: There's no need for two objects to have FK relationships to one another.

Comment: It's strange that there should be a `unique key` constraint in a regular ForeignKey field. Did you convert the `owner` field from some other field with an `unique=True` contraint?

Comment: Yeah I agree with you Rob, but I have inherited this project from some other programmer and I need to work with it like it is...

Comment: @Haken Lid Nope mate, this was tested with a empty database.. so I doubt it was conversion...

Comment: Maybe SQL server or the database adaptor has problems with fields called `owner`? In other words, it could be some table namespace bug. The error message says something about `'dbo.owner'`, which seems to be some database internal table. So it seems strange that this trival application code should insert anything there.

Comment: Try to get the specific SQL query that causes this error, and add to the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148005/how-can-i-get-query-for-save-in-django

Comment: Upon further investigation I've came to conclusion that SQL Server does not support ForeignKey that can store multiple NULL values... Don't know the workaround for this but gonna keep looking and post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The label owner is the problem, try:

```
dog.owner_id = owner.id
```